integration fails xeokit-sdk
How can I integrate 'xeokit-bim-viewer' into an Angular project to enable file uploading and generate BIM views?

Cloned the 'xeokit-bim-viewer' repository from GitHub using the command: git clone https://github.com/xeokit/xeokit-bim-viewer
Navigated into the cloned repository directory using: cd xeokit-bim-viewer
Installed the necessary dependencies with npm using: npm install


